# Whats wrong with my proof

Tags: geometry, proof-verification

I am trying to find the angle $BCB'$

[image]

Here's my solution:
[image]

But doesn't match with the answer given in the book. Its got to be $27.5^\circ$. Whats wrong with my solution?

Comment: your calculation is unnecessary. see here https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Inscribed_Angle_Theorem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your angles $\gamma$ and $\beta$ are equal because the triangle is isosceles. That means you can write the equation $2\gamma+125^\circ=180^\circ$.

The proof is a little confusing, because you're using $\gamma$ for both an unknown angle, and also for the radius of the circle. However, in your second application of the law of cosines, you plugged in the wrong values in the $2ab\cos\theta$ part.

Comment: @G Tony JacobsDamn right! $a\neq r$, Is it so?

Comment: Yeah, you got it.

Answer (score 0):

Draw the chord BB`. Then the angle subtended at the circumference is half the angle subtended at the centre (it's a well-known theorem of geometry).

Comment: But whats wrong with mine proof?

Comment: I don't know, I can't follow it. Read here for more info on circles and angles: http://www.benjamin-mills.com/maths/Year11/circle-theorems-proof.pdf